# Android in app billing issue

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I am using [this](http://www.anddev.org/advanced-tutorials-f21/simple-inapp-billing-payment-t52060.html) sample program to do `in-app-billing`. My phone version id `2.1-update 1` and my android market version code is `2002306`. But it is not working. I am stuck with this screen 
 [image] 
 Here is my log

`W GTalkService: [DataMsgMgr] broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent { act=android.intent.action.REMOTE_INTENT cat=[com.android.vending.billing.IN_APP_NOTIFY] (has extras) }`
`W GTalkService: TODO: implement reportNoReceiverError!`
`D vending : [1] BaseBuyPageActivity.onOrderResponse(): state: CART_PURCHASE response: [PurchaseResult=OK]`
`D         : unable to unlink '/data/data/com.android.vending/cache/AVMC_PSU0FfaW5hcHA6Y29tLmJsdW5kZWxsLnRlc3Q6YW5kcm9pZC50ZXN0LnB1cmNoYXNlZA': No such file or directory (errno=2)`
`D         : unable to unlink '/data/data/com.android.vending/cache/AVMC_SU0FfaW5hcHA6Y29tLmJsdW5kZWxsLnRlc3Q6YW5kcm9pZC50ZXN0LnB1cmNoYXNlZA': No such file or directory (errno=2)`
**Did my android market app not support in app billing?** 
Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Hi Sandy,Can you able to solve this issue? As myself got stuck with the same on same phone having `Android 2.1 update-1`.